# ESRI JS API is stripping hrefs

Tags: arcgis-js-api

ESRI's JS API seems to be stripping out the hrefs of URLs.

Here I set up a static link. Then I attempt to put it in the description. The link text and target="blank" are rendered but the link's href (test/) is blank!

```
    {% for project in projects %}

    var link = "<a target='blank' href='test'>Legal Description</a>";
    console.log(link) // This prints as expected with href intact.

    var attributes = {
        Name: "{{project.description}}",
        Description: link // strips out the href?!?!?!?!
    }
```

[image]

It SHOULD be localhost:8000/projects/test but there is no test href.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arcgis-js-api [sanitizes html content in popups for security reasons](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/js-api-arcgis/mapping/using-html-with-popups-in-the-arcgis-api-for-javascript/).  I'm not sure how you're defining your popups or using the `attributes` variable, but you'll want to create a [PopupTemplate](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-PopupTemplate.html), and its its `content` property to do what you want.  You can do it like the linked article recommends, or you can use a `CustomContent` instance for the popupTemplate `content` property.